ESXi datastore full after snapshot/backup
I have an ESXI Essentials 6.7 U3 host. Two datastores with 1 VM in each. In datastore1 i still have space available in VMFS. In datastore2 my single VM uses all the disk space (Thick).
So what happened? When trying to perform a backup (MS SCDPM) ESXI created a snapshot (and disk 000002.vmdk) in the datastore, crashing the VM, as there was no more disk space.
So I canceled the backup, but the machine was already experiencing a disk space error. So I shut down the VM. Later I tried to perform another backup using another tool (AOMEI) with the VM turned off. It was taking too long, so I canceled again. As a result, the disk space problem only got worse because it created a new snapshot (and disk 000003.vmdk).
Next I moved the 000002 and 000003 (ctk.vmdk, vmdk) and vmsm snapshots to a folder in the other datastore (datastore1). I downloaded and changed the vmx to try to start the machine from the main vmdk. I received an incorrect UID reference error. When trying to return the VMDK files from datastore1 to the original datastore2 folder, I was unable to do so because there was no more disk space. The files 000002-sesparse, 000003-sesparse.vmdk, Snapshot1.vmsn, Snapshot2.vmsn, Snapshot3.vmsn are found in the folder created in datastore1. Now ESXi recommends me to consolidate the disks, but I probably won't be able to due to disk space.
I don't need to the data from disks 000002 and 000003 (after the 1st backup).
What should i do? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
DataStore2
DataStore1

Why not move all of the files for the VM to datatore1 and edit the VMX accordingly. Then consolidate your snapshots.

You may be able to use VMware converter to download the VM as an OVA and convert to thin provision then re-upload. Or if you're able to rollback the snapshots then delete them, it may give you some space.

@joeqwerty There is not enougth free space on datastore 1 for this operation. Datastore1 has free space about just over half the size of datastore2.

My best shot now is to add a new disk to esxi, expand the datastore, copy the files from datastore1 back to datastore2 and see what happens.

Solved with some caveats...
I actually added a new disk, expanded the datastore2, detached the VM, changed the vmx to point to 000001.vmdk and reatached the VM. It didn't work.
So I changed the vmx to point to the main vmdk file. Worked but I lost a week of work. As this is a Zabbix server and there were very few updates to the maps, it was an acceptable loss of information.
Thanks you all! Hope it helps people on the same desperate situation.
